# Visifire inquiry

Tags: silverlight, xaml, visifire

I am making a bar graph in visifire and I want to make a custom legend.
I already achieved the custom legend but I want to stack it vertically.

Here is my code:

```
                    <visifire:Chart.PlotArea>
                        <visifire:PlotArea ShadowEnabled="false"></visifire:PlotArea>
                    </visifire:Chart.PlotArea>
                    <visifire:Chart.Legends>
                        <visifire:Legend x:Name="Legend0" Height="30" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" EntryMargin="5"
                        FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold" ShadowEnabled="False" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" LightingEnabled="False" />
                    </visifire:Chart.Legends>
                    <visifire:Chart.Series>
                        <visifire:DataSeries RenderAs="Column" LabelEnabled="True" Margin="-1,0,1,0" ShowInLegend="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" LegendText="Candidates" DataSource="{Binding PositionLevelRecruitmentList}">
                            <visifire:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                                <visifire:DataMapping MemberName="AxisXLabel" Path="FullCodeAndLevel"></visifire:DataMapping>
                                <visifire:DataMapping MemberName="YValue" Path="ApplicantCount"></visifire:DataMapping>
                            </visifire:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                        </visifire:DataSeries>
                        <visifire:DataSeries RenderAs="Column" LabelEnabled="True" Margin="5,0,1,0" ShowInLegend="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" LegendText="Required" DataSource="{Binding PositionLevelRecruitmentList}">
                            <visifire:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                                <visifire:DataMapping MemberName="YValue" Path="RequiredCount"></visifire:DataMapping>
                            </visifire:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                        </visifire:DataSeries>
                        <visifire:DataSeries RenderAs="Column" LabelEnabled="True" Margin="5,0,1,0" ShowInLegend="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" LegendText="Fulfilled" DataSource="{Binding PositionLevelRecruitmentList}">
                            <visifire:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                                <visifire:DataMapping MemberName="YValue" Path="FulfilledCount"></visifire:DataMapping>
                            </visifire:DataSeries.DataMappings>
                        </visifire:DataSeries>
                    </visifire:Chart.Series>
                </visifire:Chart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting MaxWidth="100" in Legend.

http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Reference/Attribute_Reference/maxwidth.htm